# Can't invoke either make it static or add a no-args error message don't understand the logic

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

So I am trying to call a test using the @Test Annotations and calling a properties file for the variables I need. I am trying to be specific as possible so you guys can follow whats going on, but the problem is I don't understand how the error I am receiving affects what I am testing. I will try to explain and make clear.

```
package dataSheet;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Enumeration;
    import java.util.Properties;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
    import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;

    import toolsBS.Login;

    public class ReadFileData extends Login {
        WebDriver driver;
        Login objLogin; // Declare a variable of type Login

        public ReadFileData(WebDriver driver) {
            super(driver);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        File file = new File(
                "C:\\Users\\andy.williams\\BlueSource\\src\\main\\java\\dataSheet\\dataFile.properties");

        FileInputStream fileInput;
        {
            try {
                fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        {
            // load properties file
            try {
                prop.load(fileInput);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void Setup() {
            String browser = prop.getProperty("dataFile.browser");
            String getURL = prop.getProperty("dataFile.URL");
            String strUsername = prop.getProperty("dataFile.Username");
            String strPassword = prop.getProperty("dataFile.Password");
            if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) { // Compares this String to
                // another String, ignoring case considerations. Two
                // strings are considered equal ignoring case if
                // they are of the same length and corresponding characters in the
                // two strings are equal ignoring case.
                driver = new FirefoxDriver(); // Construct a new object and store a
                // reference to it in the variable.

            }

            else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) { // Compares this String
                // to another String, ignoring case considerations. Two
                // strings are considered equal ignoring case if they are of the
                // same length and corresponding characters in the two strings are
                // equal ignoring case.
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                        "C:\\Users\\andy.williams\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe"); // Set
                // to
                // specified
                // Browser
                driver = new ChromeDriver(); // Construct a new object and store a
                // reference to it in the variable.
            }

            else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("InternetExplorer")) {
                // Compares this String to another String, ignoring case
                // considerations. Two strings are considered equal
                // ignoring case if they are of the same length and
                // corresponding characters in the two strings are equal ignoring
                // case.

                System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",
                        "C:\\Users\\andy.williams\\Desktop\\IEDriverServer.exe"); // Set
                // to
                // specified
                // Browser
                driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(); // Construct a new object and
                // store a reference to it
                // in the variable.

            }
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // Set
                                                                                // Specified
                                                                                // Time
                                                                                // Before
                                                                                // Timeout

            driver.get(getURL); // Call desired parameter to initiate the URL
            // Selection
            driver.manage().window().maximize(); // Maximize WebDriver window

            objLogin = new Login(driver); // Construct a new object and store a
            // reference to it in the variable.
            objLogin.loginToBlueSource(strUsername, strPassword); // Calling method
                                                                    // from login
                                                                    // class
                                                                    // assigning
                                                                    // desired
                                                                    // Username and
                                                                    // Password

        }

    }
```

Here is my Data File

```
 # This file is used to store URL,browser and Login Credentials

    browser=chrome
    URL=http://bluesourcestaging.herokuapp.com/login
    Username=adam.thomas
    Password=asdf
```

Now I will show you my test that I am calling.

```
package calendarPage;

    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.testng.Assert;
    import org.testng.Reporter;
    import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
    import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    import toolsBS.Login;
    import calendar.Calendar;
    import dataSheet.ReadFileData;

    public class Practice extends ReadFileData {
        WebDriver driver;
        Login objLogin; // Declare a variable of type Login
        Calendar objCal; // Declare a variable of type Calendar

        public Practice(WebDriver driver) {
            super(driver);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Test
        // Call the Current Test
        public void Practice() { // Call Method
            Setup(); // Call Setup from ReadFileData Class
            objCal = new Calendar(driver); // Construct a new object and store a
                                            // reference to it in the variable.
            Assert.assertTrue(objCal.CalendarPageLoaded(), // Assert Method
                                                            // called returns value
                                                            // of True, otherwise
                                                            // state the page didn't
                                                            // load
                    "Calendar Page didn't Load");
            Reporter.log("Success, the Calendar Page Loaded<br>"); // Reports
                                                                    // success of
                                                                    // the desired
                                                                    // Test/Method

        }

        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        @AfterTest
        // The annotated method will be run after all the test methods belonging to
        // the classes inside the <test> tag have run.
        public void closeBrowser() {

            driver.getCurrentUrl();
            driver.quit(); // close browser after each test
        }
    }
```

Finally, here is the error I am receiving.

```
[TestNG] Running:
      C:\Users\andy.williams\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--300217712\testng-customsuite.xml

    FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterTest closeBrowser
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:178)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.afterRun(TestRunner.java:1014)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:621)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)

    FAILED: Practice
    org.testng.TestNGException: 
    Can't invoke public void calendarPage.Practice.Practice(): either make it static or add a no-args constructor to your class
        at org.testng.internal.Utils.checkInstanceOrStatic(Utils.java:795)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:40)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)


    ===============================================
        Default test
        Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
        Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
    ===============================================


    ===============================================
    Default suite
    Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
    Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
    ===============================================



    I am not sure what I am doing wrong as I thought my code logic was correct.
```

Comment: Please edit your question and replace the images with the code, the images aren't large enough to read the text (might just be my monitor?). If the code is long then it will have scrollbars attached to it.

Comment: This has been updated my apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't defined a no-arg constructor:

```
public Practice(){
 ...
}
```

You've defined a public void method called Practice, and the IDE does give you a warning on it.

Comment: My apologies I am still not sure how to handle this. I see that I am getting an error message explaining what you are saying but I thought I had define a no-arg constructor. I defined a constructor up above the @Test Annotation and the method called below if supposed to kick off the test so I don't understand what I need to edit.

Comment: You've typed in public void Practice(), which is a METHOD returning void. Remove the void to make it a constructor.

Comment: So the "Public void Practice" needs to have void removed even though its a method? Every time i have ran an @Test Annotation I have called a method in the past why is this different now?

Comment: You need a no arg constructor anyway. If you want to keep the code you have under public void Practice() as a test method, rename it.